# Reset timer on msp430

Tags: c, timer, reset, msp430

Using CCS, embededded programming, MSP430F63736A

In my app I´m usingTimer A to switching LED(ON/OFF) for various time.

For example:
Led is ON - 0.5 sec
Led is OFF- 3 sec

I need to reset timer when it reach the value in register TA1CCR0. These times(0.5 s and 3 s) are in the register TA1CCR0. The problem is, that if I change the value of register TA1CCR0 from 0.5 sec to 3 sec, it will count from 0.5 to 3 sec. And I need a full 3 sec so I need a reset timer.

Thats the interrupt routine where I´m switching LED

```
    if (P4OUT == 0x00)
    {

        P4OUT ^= BIT6; // LED ON
        TA1CCR0 = (sekunda*t1);  //t1- 3 s.... pc 2s
    }

    else
    {

        P4OUT = 0x00;
        TA1CCR0 = (sekunda*t2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which timer mode are you using, up or continuous? Why? And why aren't you using set/reset mode for the CCR?

Comment: You should set Timer A Counter register (TAR), instead of Capture Compare register to change the counter value. It's better stopping timer before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Which counter mode are you using? You need to set the mode by writing to the `TA1CTL` register. The modes are:

```
#define MC_0                (0x0000)  /* Timer A mode control: 0 - Stop */
#define MC_1                (0x0010)  /* Timer A mode control: 1 - Up to CCR0 */
#define MC_2                (0x0020)  /* Timer A mode control: 2 - Continuous up */
#define MC_3                (0x0030)  /* Timer A mode control: 3 - Up/Down */
```

"Continuous" mode is typically the most used one. It counts until the overflow of the timer register, then restarts from zero. If you have it enabled, *add* to CCR continuously rather than setting it to the interval value:

```
TA1CCR0 += (sekunda*t1);
```

You can also use the "up" mode. In that case the timer counter should automatically reset to zero after reaching CCR. If you're modifying CCR within the ISR and then apparently this reset does not happen, you can modify the timer counter register (`TAR` or `TA1R`) by subtracting the value of the shortest period. Do not just set the timer register to zero, as it's usually not a good coding practice: it opens doors for timing inaccuracy accumulation in case the ISR calls are occasionally delayed (e.g. because some other interrupt is execution for multiple ticks).

Comment: using UP mode, but the probemist when I change value of register TACCR0 from lower to higher,  Timer  is not counting from 0 but he keep counting from previous  value

Comment: @kfx I don't understand that yet, but I'm flagging my comment for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

In your ISR add an offset to TA1CCR0 and not reset it:

Say you want a 1 sec delay after the first interrupt, and let's say to generate 1 sec delay the timer must count up to 50000. So what you need to do in you ISR is TA1CCR0 +=50000.

In your case:

```
if (P4OUT == 0x00)
{

    P4OUT ^= BIT6; // LED ON
    TA1CCR0    +=    (sekunda*t1);  //t1- 3 s.... pc 2s
}

else
{

    P4OUT = 0x00;
    TA1CCR0    +=    (sekunda*t2);
}
```

}

For an a complete example please see